# CSS - White space around top and left of page

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web app and unfortunately I have a white border around the top and left of the page. I have set the html and body padding and margin to 0px but it doesn't seem to be having any effect on it. Inside of the body is a single iframe and when I preview the site and I go on inspect element it shows that the padding is on the body...

Here is the code - if anyone could take a look that would be great!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>index</title>
    <style>
        html {
            height:100%;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            margin: 0px !important;
            padding: 0px !important;
            height:100%;
        }

    </style>

    <!-- copy these lines to your document head: -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=320" />

    <!-- end copy -->

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- copy these lines to your document: -->

    <div id="index_hype_container" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;" aria-live="polite">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.hyperesources/index_hype_generated_script.js?4823"></script>
    </div>

    <!-- end copy -->


  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3edyohc/)

Comment: Could you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing where the error is?

Comment: Iframe doesn't inherit its parent documents stylesheets. Perhaps you're seeing the iframe's body margin

Comment: @joe_young Here: https://jsfiddle.net/g3edyohc/ you can see the white border in the output

Comment: @rzr Ok any suggestions to make it fill it completely?

Comment: Have you set iframe margins and frame border to zero?  For example: iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"

Comment: @mugé Yes i have. See this code:                                                       <iframe src='http://channel59.de'
 id="my-frame"
 marginwidth="0"
 marginheight="0"
 frameborder="0"
 scrolling="no"
 height="100%"
 width="100%">
</iframe>

Comment: How about your 'channel59.de' source, have you checked any design padding/margin/frame/border issues in your source file?

Comment: @mugé no that works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the margins of the `#my-iframe` to a negative number, e.g. `-10px`:

```
#my-iframe {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -10px;
}
```

This may cut a *small* section of the iframed site off, but judging by the look of the site a few pixels off the edge won't do much damage.

Comment: I played around with this until I found that -8px was the correct value :)